# Comando para instalar Symfony 3 en Windows

Tags: symfony3

Cuando voy a descargar e instalar *Symfony* con el siguiente comando por consola:

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

... me sale el siguiente error:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.

¿Por qué pasa esto y cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Aún no me queda claro que tiene que ver el tag vb.net con symfony

Comment: Fué una equivocación de mi parte sorry.

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer ping desde la máquina que da el error a `symfony.com`?

Comment: Hice ping a symfony.com y no encontró el host, pero si puedo entrar al sitio symfony.com, no entiendo porque no hace ping pero si puedo entrar a esa dirección por el navegador?

Comment: pudiera ser que estàs conectado a internet a travès de un servidor proxy, si ese es el caso, debes establecer la direccion del mismo al sistema operativo

Answer (score 2):

Mejor instala composer y desde él generas los nuevos proyectos!

Bajalo y lo instalas!
https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Luego desde la terminal te diriges a la carpeta donde deseas crear el nuevo proyecto:

Ej:
C:\xampp\htdocs

Y ya estando en la carpeta donde quieres crear el proyecto, usas:

composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.8.*"

Lo que esta en las comillas dobles es la version a instalar, sino le pones version te instala la ultima estable (actualmente).

Espero te sirva.

Para mas info:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html -> busca: Creating Symfony Applications with Composer

Y si quieres profundizar mas, este hombre a traducido al español toda la documentación para prepararse para la certificación.

https://diego.com.es/certificacion-symfony

A disfrutar!!!

Answer (score 1):

Este problema suele suceder porque se lo hace desde la consola de Windows sin todo lo necesario.

Te recomiendo instalar primero git y luego laragon (que es un servidor web)

Te recomiendo laragon porque tiene una terminal desde donde puedes instalar directamente symfony o ejecutar estos comandos sin problemas.

Hoy acabé de hacer un pequeño demo y en 5 minutos tenía instalado Symfony 3.2.8 y creada la ruta amigable en mi caso

```
http://picoyplaca.dev
http://picoyplaca.dev/app_dev.php/
```

Pico y placa es el nombre de la app tu le puedes poner lo que creas conveniente.

Saludos