# Error al instalar Symfony

Tags: symfony

He seguido las instrucciones para instalar symfony de la pagina oficial pero al meter el comando: `php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"` me da el siguiente error:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https"
>   - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code
>   on line 1 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(h
>   ttps://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
>   in Command line code on line 1
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(ht tps://symfony.com/installer): failed to
>   open stream: Invalid argument in Command line code on line 1

Comment: Intenta cambiando el https por http.

Comment: También puedes acceder con tu browser a https://symfony.com/installer y te descarga el archivo `symfony.phar` el cual puedes renombrarlo a `symfony`. Recuerda que ese programa php es compatible con php 5.4 en adelante.  
Otra opción sería simplemente utilizar composer, lo descargas de https://getcomposer.org/download/ y creas tu proyecto symfony con :    
`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estas teniendo es que no tenes habilitado el modulo de ssl para que puedas hacer requests https desde php. C0mo no tenés el modulo habilitado, devuelve un error al tratar de hacer la petición. Lo que falla es el

```
file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer')
```

Lo tenes que habilitar en el php.ini que estes utilizando.

Si estas usando XAMPP descomenta la linea (borrale el ; )

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

en

```
/apache/bin/php.ini
```

y reinicia el apache

Answer (score 1):

Mejor instala composer y desde él generas los nuevos proyectos!

Bajalo y lo instalas! https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Luego desde la terminal te diriges a la carpeta donde deseas crear el nuevo proyecto:

Ej: C:\xampp\htdocs

Y ya estando en la carpeta donde quieres crear el proyecto, usas:

composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.8.*"

Lo que esta en las comillas dobles es la version a instalar, sino le pones version te instala la ultima estable (actualmente).

Espero te sirva.

Para mas info:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html -> busca: Creating Symfony Applications with Composer

Y si quieres profundizar mas, este hombre a traducido al español toda la documentación para prepararse para la certificación.

https://diego.com.es/certificacion-symfony

A disfrutar!!!

Comment: Fernando estas realizando respuestas duplicadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70121/comando-para-instalar-symfony-3-en-windows/99816#99816 revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Gracias, podría responder poniendo el link a la respuesta?

Comment: Poner un enlace a la otra respuesta sería mejor como comentario en la pregunta que como respuesta. El problema de las respuestas duplicadas es que _generalmente_ son una señal de que hay algo que no va bien: o las preguntas son duplicadas también (por eso la misma respuesta, en cuyo caso habría que marcar la pregunta como duplicada), o la respuesta es demasiado genérica (matar mosquitos a cañonazos) o directamente no responde a la pregunta.